# Trigonometry Equations (Sum to Product)

Tags: trigonometry

I am struggling with how to determine which solutions are not part of the solution set. For instance, in $\sin(6x)+\sin(x)=0$, I used the sum to product theorem and got $\sin(7x)\cos(5x)=0$. I got solutions $(\pi/7)n$ but I didn't discard some of the solutions because they wouldn't work for the $\sin(6x)+\sin(x)=0$. Do you know how to solve this by using a simpler method?

Comment: You should have got $\sin(\frac72x)\cos(\frac52x)=0$.

Comment: U applied the sum product theorem wrongly. $\sin 6x + \sin x = 2sin{\frac{7x}{2}}\cos{\frac{5x}{2}}$.

Comment: Thank you for telling me. No wonder why I kept messing up. It was all because of arithmetic mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative method:
$$\eqalign{\sin6x+\sin x=0\quad
  &\Leftrightarrow\quad \sin x=-\sin6x\cr
  &\Leftrightarrow\quad x=-6x+2k\pi\ \hbox{or}\ x=6x+(2k+1)\pi\cr
  &\Leftrightarrow\quad x=\frac{2k\pi}7\ \hbox{or}\ x=-\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{5}\ .\cr}$$

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way of solving:
$$\sin 6x + \sin x = 0$$
$$\implies\sin 6x = -\sin x$$
$$\implies\sin 6x = sin(-x)$$
$$\implies 6x = n\pi + (-1)^{n+1}x $$
$$\implies 6x-(-1)^{n+1}x= n\pi$$
$$\implies x(6+(-1)^n)= n\pi$$
$$\implies x = \frac{n\pi}{6+(-1)^n}$$, where n $\in  \Bbb{  Z}$.